# Facebook style url fetching

Tags: social-network

Does anybody have an idea, how to do a facebook url or link fetcher just link the one on facebook.

I have tried and have got a script but how to convert that into a drupal module for it to work.

Let me try to be more clear.

If you type a link on facebook it will go and get the image, meta description and other info from that link.

This is what i want to achieve.

If a user enters a link, what or how can i pull the data like image, meta description, etc etc from the link provided by the user.

[Facebook-style link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_link) is the perfect example of what i need but it is only for drupal 6 and i need it for drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using any of these below modules :

1. [Facebook Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/fbconnect)
2. [Simple FB Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect)
3. [Drupal For Facebook](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb)